# Test string with regex?

Tags: java, android, regex

Currently I am testing a string for a prompt on a switch.

```
if (!parseCommand.contains("switch#")
```

But I have just realized that the user can change the name from switch to something with numbers or letters. It will always end with # however. What should I do to test this in a  more general way? Use `String.matches` to test for a# with a lookback for a-zA-Z0-9?

Comment: Well, you answered your question towards the end. Yes, you need to use `String.matches`.

Comment: Was just wondering was it the correct way. Thanks

Comment: In many cases you can simplify `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `\w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as u said use String.matches function nly- probably this way

```
parseCommand.matches("\\w+#$")
```

which makes sure it always ends with '#'

Comment: Why the double backslashes? Like this you would escape the 2nd backslash as a character, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Simon: Single backslash would be an invalid escape sequence. You need to escape the backslash (in java) to use it as one backslash (in regex).

Comment: Oh yeah, java, didn't look at the question tags, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!parseCommand.matches ("\\w+#.*"))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `^\w+#$` be more appropriate? _"It will always end with # however"_